# Check for day range and no

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have the following data sheet:

[image]

As you can see I have a date and a no which is a string.

Now I want to filter out all dates which have the same number in a +-20 day intervall around the date. So for example:

If the `12.2.2014` has the value `a` then it gets a `1` and if the `3.2.2014` has the value `a` it gets also a `1`. In contrast if the value `15.1.2014` has the value `a` it gets a `0` because it is not in the `+-20 day range`. If there exists two rows like in the example below with `10.07.2002` and value `d` then it gets a 0 because there is no other day in a `20 day intervall` around it.

[image]

My implementation idea is: Calculate for each value and date the difference of the dates and if it is less or equal than 20 and greater and equal to 1 then give out a 1 else a 0.

Can this be done in excel?

I really appreciate any suggestions

PS.: I hope that I showed the problem clearly!

**UPDATE**

Using this formula I get:

`=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$32;B2;$A$2:$A$32;">"&(A2-20);$A$2:$A$32;"<"&(A2+20))-1`

[image]

see col `E`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (adjust the `$B$2:$B$32` etc to your actual data range):

```
 =COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$32,B2,
                $A$2:$A$32,">" & (A2-20),
                $A$2:$A$32,"<" & (A2+20))-1
```

`-1` is to avoid counting the row the formula is on.

To give only 0 or 1:

```
 =MIN(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$32,B2,
                $A$2:$A$32,">" & (A2-20),
                $A$2:$A$32,"<" & (A2+20))-1,1)
```

Comment: Wow thx for your answer! Please see my update if I adapted the formula right. Is it also possible to only give `0` and `1` values out?